# Error while running .each loop in ruby

Tags: ruby, if-statement, each

I am trying to implement server side validations, to do that i receive the form values in the variable @value

```
    @value =  {"prev_school":{"name":"","class":"Nursery"},"sibling": {"name":""}}

    @validate = {"prev_school":[{"name":["is_mandatory","is_alphabets"]}}
```

In @variable I have defined the methods that need to be called for each field. My question is when I run the following code

```
     @value.each do |key,val| 
         @validate.each do |k,v|
            if k == key puts v end 
        end     
    end
```

I am getting an error pointing to the if statement

```
  syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting kDO or '{' or '('
```

Could somebody please help with this.

Cheers! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want one of these:

```
@value.each do |key,val| 
  @validate.each do |k,v|
    if k == key
      puts v
    end 
  end     
end
```

or

```
@value.each do |key,val| 
  @validate.each do |k,v|
    puts v if k == key
  end     
end
```

Your version is a syntax error because Ruby doesn't know that you mean to end the `if` between `key` and `puts` so it is trying to interpret `key puts v` as an argument for `==` but gets confused.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was right! That racked by brains for so long!

Answer (score 1):

And you have to define hash either trough { "key" => "value" } syntax, or with { key: value } - in Ruby 1.9. So you variables should look like this:

```
@value =
{
  "prev_school" => {"name" => "", "class" => "Nursery"},
  "sibling" => {"name" => ""}
}
@validate = {"prev_school" => [{"name" => ["is_mandatory","is_alphabets"]}]}
```

In @validate you miss `]` between two final `}`.